# Download a file using HttpURLConnection - Connection timed out error

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I have written a java program to download a file from a url - [NSE Bhavcopy](https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2017/NOV/cm06NOV2017bhav.csv.zip)

But I am getting "Exception in thread 'main' java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect", I tried the following permutation & combinations but no luck.

1. With proxy & without proxy
2. With authentication & without
3. Tried with different url's

Following is the code & trace for reference, can some one help me please

```
 String myUrl = "https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2017/NOV/cm06NOV2017bhav.csv.zip";
 String fileName = "d:\\download.zip";

 Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("10.100.1.124", 3128));

 URL url = new URL(myUrl);
 HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);

 String accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
 String agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.83 Safari/537.1";

 uc.setRequestProperty("Accept", accept);
 uc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", agent);
 uc.setRequestMethod("GET");
 uc.setConnectTimeout(15*1000);
 Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());uc.connect();  //I get "connection timed out error" for this line
```

Trace

```
     Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(FileUtils.java:844)
at cashflow.downloadMTM.option2(downloadMTM.java:76)
at cashflow.downloadMTM.main(downloadMTM.java:71)
```

Comment: Can't say what the problem might be because it worked for me. Did you try pasting the URL in the browser to see if it would download.

Comment: Yes, it is working if I paste the URL in the browser. I have writeen .Net equivalent code using webclient which is working fine.

Comment: Finally I found some solution

Answer (score 0):

downloadFile("http://www.bseindia.com/download/BhavCopy/Equity/EQ_ISINCODE_071117.zip", "D:\Market Feeds\BSE Bhavcopy\");

```
public static void downloadFile(String source, String destination) throws Exception { 

    try{
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("10.100.1.124", 3128));

    URL oracle = new URL(source);
    URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection(proxy);

    InputStream in = yc.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destination + "\\bhavcopy.zip");
    copySource2Dest(in, out, 1024);
    out.close();

    extractFolder(destination + "\\bhavcopy.zip", destination);

    Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(destination, "bhavcopy.zip");
    boolean succ = Files.deleteIfExists(path);

    System.out.println("Download is successfull");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error in downloading : " + e);
    }
}

 public static void copySource2Dest(InputStream input, OutputStream output, int bufferSize)
         throws IOException {
             byte[] buf = new byte[bufferSize];
             int n = input.read(buf);
             while (n >= 0) {
                 output.write(buf, 0, n);
                 n = input.read(buf);
             }
             output.flush();
         }

public static void extractFolder(String zipFile,String extractFolder) 
{
    try
    {
        int BUFFER = 2048;
        File file = new File(zipFile);

        ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(file);
        String newPath = extractFolder;

        new File(newPath).mkdir();
        Enumeration zipFileEntries = zip.entries();

        ZipEntry entry;

        // Process each entry
        while (zipFileEntries.hasMoreElements())
        {
            // grab a zip file entry
            entry = (ZipEntry) zipFileEntries.nextElement();
            String currentEntry = entry.getName();

            File destFile = new File(newPath, currentEntry);
            File destinationParent = destFile.getParentFile();

            // create the parent directory structure if needed
            destinationParent.mkdirs();

            if (!entry.isDirectory())
            {
                BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(zip
                .getInputStream(entry));
                int currentByte;
                // establish buffer for writing file
                byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];

                // write the current file to disk
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
                BufferedOutputStream dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos,
                BUFFER);

                // read and write until last byte is encountered
                while ((currentByte = is.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                    dest.write(data, 0, currentByte);
                }
                dest.flush();
                dest.close();
                is.close();
            }
        }
        zip.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("ERROR: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```